# Can't implement Aeron Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar

I'm trying to implement Aeron Calendar on a personal project that I'm working at but I'm having a hard time implementing it.

The script is working, but the calendar isn't properly styled as the example shown on their website and for some reason the calendar is showing up on the far left instead of right after the input field.

Their example: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links, so you can find their example in their website. (electricprism.com/aeron/calendar/)

My web app: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk7ER.png)

I tried following their guide but I guess I missed some important step.

I download the `calendar.js` and `mootools.js` from their website so maybe it could be a version thing?!

Here's the link for my repository with the entire code: https://github.com/lucasmonteirof/activities_logger

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of linking to Github, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The images were missing. Couldn't find them on the website so I had to save it manually one by one. It worked though.